# Noisy images from Canon PowerShot SX150 IS

Tags: canon, image-quality

I purchased "Canon PowerShot SX150 IS Point & Shoot 12x" around 9-10 months ago. I was satisfied with image quality. But from last 3-4 months, it is not able to snap good quality pictures as it was. Even outdoor photos are noisy.

I can see noise on picture, even if I take high size picture. My mobile, Samsung Ace 5880 (5mp), can take pictures better than my camera and the output image size is much lesser.

Please tell me how can I decrease noise, increase sharpness or can do other settings to increase image quality.

*Noise filter is on
*I have tried auto and program mode both

Comment: Can you post comparable pictures? Have you tried resetting the camera?

Comment: If you do post pictures, please try and include EXIF data with them.

Comment: As stated, please post a picture from when you thought the images were cleaner, and then a more recent image that you believe to be noisy. Include EXIF data on both, please.

Comment: what is EXIF data? Yes I had reset camera settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to having your ISO set too high. I've seen you can actually set the ISO on this modelof camera. As the ISO hasn't been mentioned I can only asume this is the case.

ISO 100: Excellent, fine clear quality. Use on bright sunny days.

ISO 400: Sunny/cloudy days. A pretty good general setting to have.

ISO 800: Cloudy daytime

ISO 1600: Low light, dark daytime

ISO 3200+: Sunset/night time, though a long shutter speed, low iso and tripod would produce excellent results. But this is getting into much more deeper side of photography.

Comment: It might be a cause. Because I set it highest. I'll set it to automatic then'll try. thanks

Comment: Yes that sounds like it. You're welcome. If you're using Automatic it would be best to shoot in a park on a sunny or bright day and then again perhaps inside a slightly darkened room. Then compare the two. The darkened room will have more noise. The sunny day pic should really have quite minimal noise if any at all.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I tried some snaps in my room in dim light at 6am with 1600, 80, auto ISO. I got best quality on 80 but it was not completely established image. On auto I got average and on 1600 I got max noisy picture. Initially I was not expecting any fruitful answer on my question.

Comment: For curiosity; can you tell me why pictures are so clear and of less size from my mobile(5mp)? Do I need some extra settings in my camera

Comment: Glad you've solved the problem, 80 is a very high quality ISO.  This could be a number of reasons depending on what your shooting and the type of camera phone. I would asume you using iphone 4 or samsung galaxy (early models)? The thing is, good quality imagery is not solely down to Mega Pixels generally speaking. It's down to light, aperture and iso settings in the strictest form. Camera phones tend to use automatic settings to find the best image. This doesn't give you a great amount of diversity and options but it does give you a good quality image.